# Can we return class object in wcf?

Tags: wcf, class, service

I am going to use my first app classes in my second app through wcf.
Now I want to know it is possible to call my classes from first app with all properties and methods related it?

Comment: please don't send google search result as answer, I have read all of them. I am looking for technical response

Comment: If you're **sharing** the classes between your two apps, by means of a common assembly - then yes, you can use everything in your classes. If you're using strict WCF (no assembly sharing), then **NO** you cannot use any **functionality**, since WCF is strictly an XML-based **messaging** service - it transports **data and state** - but **NOT** functionality (no code) between client and server. WCF is **not** a *remote object* mechanism (like Corba) - it's **strictly** about data messaging

Comment: To add to what Marc_s said, this means you cannot have logic in your constructor - it won't get invoked, not unless you do very specific things.